# How to create 3 columns for cards using bootstrap row class

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to display the content (which are presented in cards) of my page in three different columns using bootstrap 4 row class. How do I go about it?

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and bootstrap 4. Other bootstrap functions like carousel and nav bar are working properly.

The code for the content in the main blade file-views/layout/app.blade.php looks like this;

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     @yield('content')                   
</div>
```

Then that for the page I desire the layout-views/pages/secondpage.blade.php is;

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')

        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <h2> Page caption</h2>
        </div>

<div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card border-white">
                <div class="card-header">Heading 1</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build 
                           on the card 
                        title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card border-white">
                <div class="card-header">Heading 2</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build 
                          on the card 
                        title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card border-white">
                <div class="card-header">Heading 3</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build 
                         on the card 
                        title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

@endsection
```

I expect to see the cards arranged in three different columns, but they are all in a single column.

Comment: inspect it , and see the width applied and by which class? col-md-4 or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra div close tag, for all three
thats why you get all in one column

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card border-white">
                <div class="card-header">Heading 1</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build 
                           on the card 
                        title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--</div>-->
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card border-white">
                <div class="card-header">Heading 2</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build 
                          on the card 
                        title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--</div>-->

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card border-white">
                <div class="card-header">Heading 3</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build 
                         on the card 
                        title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--</div>-->

</div>
```

Comment: glad it solved your issue, you can give it a vote up and accept, to close your question

Answer (score 0):

This is causing due to extra div after each col-md-4 div. I have made some correction in HTML.

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="card border-white">
      <div class="card-header">Heading 1</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build
          on the card
          title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="card border-white">
    <div class="card-header">Heading 2</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build
        on the card
        title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="card border-white">
    <div class="card-header">Heading 3</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build
        on the card
        title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```